# Expression engine: Maximum number of entries allowed per membrr group

Tags: expressionengine

Is it possible to limit the number of channel entries a member can create?
I would like to set a max number per member group.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but it would require writing an extension. The logic would be something like this (assuming you're talking about limiting on the back-end ... from the front-end, if you're using a Safecracker entry form for example, you'd need to take a different approach):

1. use the [sessions_end](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/extension_hooks/global/session/index.html#sessions-end) hook
2. check to make sure you're in the control panel (`$this->EE->input->get('D') == 'cp'`)
3. check to make sure you're on the publish screen (`$this->EE->input->get('C') ==
   'content_publish'`)
4. query the database to see how many entries in `exp_channel_titles` with the `channel_id` of `$this->EE->input->get('channel_id')` belong to `$this->EE->session->userdata('member_id')`
5. if the result is greater than your allowed maximum, show them an error

That should get you started.